# Read iframe contents and store them in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe which lets say that it contains the following text:

`<h1> Hello World</h1><h2>Good Morning</h2>

<h3>Try this http://www.google.com</h3></body></html>`

I want to read the link found above and visit it. Any idea? I cannot do it using the console because I need to get the cookies from this page

Comment: Just click on the link? On a more serious note though: What do you want to achieve *programatically*? On a web page, you cannot request information from arbitrary sites without preventing the Same origin policy.

Comment: As you can see it is not a link...! :)
I want to achieve this programatically. Let's assume that I am hosting both pages. I need to achieve this because the link will change dynamically.

Comment: You have to 1. Detect the link (define the pattern first!), then 2. Use `$.ajax` to retrieve the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it unless the iframe is of the same domain as the parent page.

In case it is then you can use the following script:

```
var link = $('#iframeid').contents().find('h3').html(); //Thanks to rob for the correction
```

Then you will simply have to filter out the link from the other text from the variable.

Comment: That's invalid JavaScript. Did you mean: `$('#iframeid').contents().find('h3').html()` ?

Comment: @RobW This is jQuery isn't it? Can I store this to a variable?

Comment: @Whatever As obama would put it: Yes we can!

Comment: Tried this and it brings back null! Any idea?

Comment: Check the console for errors and paste the result here. Is the iframe from the same domain as the parent?

Answer (score 0):

Get the contents of the iframe even if it's outside your domain:

```
var link = $('#MyiFrame').contents().find('h3').text();
//now parse the link variable to what you need, maybe split it at :// 
//and the following space afterwards
```

Good luck!

Comment: "even if it's outside your domain".  You *can't* read the iFrame's content if it's not the same domain.

Comment: Most (read: secure) browsers don't allow cross-origin referencing unless there is a flag set at the server serving the resource.

Comment: I tried this as well but it doesn't return anything. Not even null... Any clue?